# logcheck: (CRON) error (grandchild #4266 failed with exit status 127)

Tags: server, cron

for my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, **logcheck** send me this log:

```
Nov 14 08:10:01 servername CRON[4265]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4266 failed with exit status 127)
Nov 14 08:10:01 servername CRON[4264]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4267 failed with exit status 127)
Nov 14 08:20:01 servername CRON[4285]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4286 failed with exit status 127)
Nov 14 08:20:01 servername CRON[4284]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4287 failed with exit status 127)
Nov 14 08:30:01 servername CRON[4294]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4295 failed with exit status 127)
Nov 14 08:30:01 servername CRON[4293]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4296 failed with exit status 127)
Nov 14 08:40:01 servername CRON[4311]: (CRON) error (grandchild #4312 failed with exit status 127)
```

this is an error of execution to cron [*127 = command not found*].
if I run the command "**crontab -l**" for each user, I do not see any cron to any user.
You have any ideas?

---

This is my /etc/crontab

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Comment: Can you please paste the output of cat /etc/crontab? I think this "command not found" could be related to what CRON is trying to run.

Comment: [This "answer"](http://askubuntu.com/q/81799/22949) by [Paulo Arruda](http://askubuntu.com/users/34914/paulo-arruda) might be removed (as it is not an attempt to answer the question), but the information it's requesting is spot-on. So in case it's removed, here it is: "*Can you please paste the output of cat /etc/crontab? I think this "command not found" could be related to what CRON is trying to run.*" Please edit your question to include that information.